# Composer cannot find drupal/commerce in a specific module

Tags: 8, commerce, composer

I'm attempting to update the dependencies of a specific module in my site. I've downloaded the module with git and navigated inside. If I run `composer validate` it says `./composer.json is valid`.
However if I run `composer update` or `composer require drupal/commerce:2.16` I get the error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package drupal/commerce could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package drupal/search_api could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

I cannot figure out what is the legit issue here.
This is the current require of my `composer.json`

```
  "require": {
    "drupal/commerce": "~2.8",
    "drupal/search_api": "~1.9",
    "picqer/php-barcode-generator": "^0.2.2",
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Drupal repository to composer.json in your project.

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
  }
]
```

Note that after you do this and run composer require/update, it will create a vendor directory in your module folder. You'll want to delete this folder, as you only want your dependencies to be added when the module is added to your project, and your project's composer.json should install the dependencies in the correct directory.

Comment: The project is fine. I'm trying to solve an issue with just this module. I'm not sure if this is the same thing.

Comment: I'd say it probably is.

Comment: Add the repo to the project, I.E. the site or the module? There hasn't been any repos added to the module so far and it works fine. I'll give it a shot tonight. Still not too clear on project / module space. Thanks

Comment: Add it to whichever composer.json is being called when that error is thrown.